# How I can fix the error in: "Fit the PCA transformer on the training data and transform the data line" and "model = svm.SVC(kernel='linear')"

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, svm

I have create this Support Vector machine model but I get errors in "Fit the PCA transformer on the training data and transform the data line"  and "model = svm.SVC(kernel='linear')"

The first error is:

```
NameError: name 'x_train' is not defined
```

The second error is:

```
NameError: name 'svm' is not defined
```

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from sklearn.svm import SVC
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
import seaborn as sns
import seaborn as sns # for data visualization

train_df = pd.read_csv('diabetes_data_upload.csv')
train_df.head()

# checking total of rows and columns
train_df.shape

# Transforming the Gender into 0 and 1
train_df["Gender"] = train_df["Gender"].map({"Male": 0, "Female": 1}).astype(int)
#Rounding the Age
train_df["Age"] = train_df.Age.round()

# Separating the data to predict the missing ages
X_train = train_df[train_df.Age.notnull()][['Age','Gender','weakness','Obesity', 'class']]
X_test = train_df[train_df.Age.isnull()][['Age','Gender','weakness','Obesity', 'class']]
y = train_df.Age.dropna()


# Just confirming if there is no more ages missing
train_df.Age.isnull().sum()

# Taking only the features that is important for now
X = train_df[['Gender', 'Age', 'weakness']]

# Taking the labels
Y = train_df['class']

# Spliting into 80% for training set and 20% for testing set so we can see our accuracy
X_train, x_test, Y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, Y, test_size=0.2, random_state=0)

# Declaring the SVC with no tunning
print(X_train.shape)
print(Y_train.shape)


from sklearn.decomposition import PCA

# Create a PCA transformer with 3 components
pca = PCA(n_components=3)

# Fit the PCA transformer on the training data and transform the data
x_train_pca = pca.fit_transform(x_train)

# Transform the test data using the PCA transformer fitted on the training data
x_test_pca = pca.transform(x_test)

# Fit the classifier on the transformed training data
classifier.fit(x_train_pca, y_train)

# Predict the labels for the transformed test data
predictions = classifier.predict(x_test_pca)

# Calculate the accuracy of the model
accuracy = classifier.score(x_test_pca, y_test)
print("Accuracy:", accuracy)


#make it binary classification problem
X = X[np.logical_or(Y==0,Y==1)]
Y = Y[np.logical_or(Y==0,Y==1)]
model = svm.SVC(kernel='linear')
clf = model.fit(X, Y)
# The equation of the separating plane is given by all x so that np.dot(svc.coef_[0], x) + b = 0.
# Solve for w3 (z)
z = lambda x,y: (-clf.intercept_[0]-clf.coef_[0][0]*x -clf.coef_[0][1]*y) / clf.coef_[0][2]


tmp = np.linspace(-5,5,30)
x,y = np.meshgrid(tmp,tmp)
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')
ax.plot3D(X[Y==0,0], X[Y==0,1], X[Y==0,2],'ob')
ax.plot3D(X[Y==1,0], X[Y==1,1], X[Y==1,2],'sr')
ax.plot_surface(x, y, z(x,y))
ax.view_init(30, 60)
plt.show()
```

Comment: you are using `x_train`, instead of `X_train`, and `svm.SVC` instead of just `SVC`. More details in my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

The two errors you mention can be solved by the following -

#### 1. NameError: name 'x_train' is not defined

This is because you are using `x_train` instead of the `X_train` variable you have defined right above. Remember, variables names are case sensitive.

```py
x_train_pca = pca.fit_transform(x_train)  # your code

x_train_pca = pca.fit_transform(X_train)  # change it to this
```

#### 2. NameError: name 'svm' is not defined

This is because you are already importing the `SVC` class using `from svm import SVC`. But while trying to instantiating the class the model you are using `svm.SVC`.

```py
model = svm.SVC(kernel='linear') # your code

model = SVC(kernel='linear')     # change it to this
```

Comment: Still the same issues.

Comment: are you using a notebook?, Please restart the kernel and please rerun each line of the code again. these changes should fix the issue. If not, please copy past teh exact error trace in completeness and add it to your question.

Comment: I think I have to convert it to numeric data.